# Short story where an alien convinces a human to exchange consciousness with it

Tags: story-identification

While reading [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188120/short-story-where-people-can-swap-minds-with-others) question, I recalled that I had read a similar story in my English textbook. The details were a bit different from this question though.
An alien (who I think is a convict) convinces a human to exchange consciousnesses with it because it wants to be free. The human appears to be reluctant but at the end, it is revealed that

> the human is suffering from some disease and will die soon and is happy to have gone through with the exchange.

I read it ~10 years ago at school and some of the details are probably wrong.

Comment: See also [What is the story in which a man and an alien are penpals?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5373/what-is-the-story-in-which-a-man-and-an-alien-are-penpals)

Comment: [Alien exchanges letters with human, tricks human into swapping bodies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153219/alien-exchanges-letters-with-human-tricks-human-into-swapping-bodies)

Comment: Looks like I didn't search well enough. My bad.

Comment: @sudhanva: Don't feel bad. It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

["Dear Pen Pal"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70706) aka "Letter from the Stars", a short story by [A. E. van Vogt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._E._van_Vogt); available for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Out_Of_This_World_Adventures_v01n01_1950-07#page/n23/mode/2up).

> Dear Pen Pal:
>
> Thanks a lot for forcing the issue. For a long time I hesitated about letting you play such a trick on yourself. You see, the government scientists analyzed the nature of that first photographic plate you sent me, and so the final decision was really up to me. I decided that anyone as eager as you were to put one over should be allowed to succeed.
>
> Now I know I didn't have to feel sorry for you. Your plan to conquer Earth wouldn't have gotten anywhere, but the fact that you had the idea ends the need for sympathy.
>
> But this time you will have realized for yourself that a man who has been paralyzed since birth, and is subject to heart attacks, cannot expect a long life span. I am happy to tell you that your once-lonely pen pal is enjoying himself, and I am happy to sign myself with a name to which I expect to become accustomed.
>
> With best wishes
> Skandar

Comment: It's been so long, I'd even forgotten that it was epistolary. Thanks for the Internet Archive link! :)